# Is there a way to add filters to custom endpoint with DTO?

Tags: filter, dto, api-platform.com

I have a custom endpoint (which does some custom aggregations), the return of this endpoint is a collection of DTO. I want to add some filters sugestions for the consumers of my api. Is this possible ? How can you do that ?

To sum up :

- I have a DTO (ApiResource but not linked to doctrine or a database).
- I have a custom GET endpoint that return a collection of DTO (filtered or not).
- I want to add filters sugestion to this endpoint.

Should i modify the hydra:search somehow ?

I tried to add ApiFilters (like i do for the entites) on my DTO but ApiFilters are linked to doctrine so it gives me the following error : `Call to a member function getClassMetadata() on null` on `vendor/api-platform/core/src/Bridge/Doctrine/Common/PropertyHelperTrait.php`

Comment: I had this too when i built a Report for chapter 9 of my [tutorial](https://github.com/metaclass-nl/tutorial-api-platform). Simpelest solution was to move the operation to the Entity resource and set its output to be the DTO class. Then it can use the ApiFilters defined on the Entity class. Your Controller will get the Entities as its input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue, to solve it I create a custom filter without the `$this->isPropertyMapped` part.

I injected the `ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Extension\FilterExtension` to my collection provider and apply my filters with
`$this->filterExtension->applyToCollection($qb, $queryNameGenerator, $resourceClass, $operationName, $context);` in order to alter the query.

Then I just need to configure my custom filter in my dto object

`@ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"columnName": "exact"})`

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\ThirdParty\ApiPlatform\Filter;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\AbstractContextAwareFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Util\QueryNameGeneratorInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;

final class SearchFilter extends AbstractContextAwareFilter
{

    protected function filterProperty(
        string $property,
        $value,
        QueryBuilder $queryBuilder,
        QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator,
        string $resourceClass,
        string $operationName = null
    ): void {
        if (
            !$this->isPropertyEnabled($property, $resourceClass)
        ) {
            return;
        }

        $parameterName = $queryNameGenerator->generateParameterName($property);

        $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];

        $queryBuilder
            ->andWhere(sprintf('%s.%s = :%s', $rootAlias, $property, $parameterName))
            ->setParameter($parameterName, $value);
    }

    public function getDescription(string $resourceClass): array
    {
        if (!$this->properties) {
            return [];
        }

        $description = [];
        foreach ($this->properties as $property => $strategy) {
            $description["regexp_$property"] = [
                'property' => $property,
                'type' => 'string',
                'required' => false,
                'swagger' => [
                    'description' => 'description',
                    'name' => $property,
                    'type' => 'type',
                ],
            ];
        }

        return $description;
    }
}
```